# Spring @Profile and @Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Does the `org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile` annotation work with `javax.persistence.Entity` annotation ?
It seems that no.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Those are completely unrelated annotations. Please describe what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @LuiggiMendoza . What I would like to do, is to enable certain hibernate entities on some spring profile and not for the default ones.

Comment: It wasn't an answer, it was a comment. Anyway, you should use `@Profile` for your configuration, and **there** you should mark the entities to load or not. In this case, `Spring` and `Hibernate` are two complete different fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring is only managing Spring components. Usually the components are stateless services.

If the class (with or without the @Entity annotation) is not created by Spring, the @Profile annotation won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you have proper structure. E.g

`com.yourapp.app.Application` <- main application, shoud have annotation @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.yourapp.config", ...})
Class that are not under com.yourapp.app package will be not loaded automatically.
The rest of the classes are not in the `app` package:

`com.yourapp.config.MyConfigLocal` <- config with annotation @Profile("local") and @EntityScan(basePackages = "com.yourapp.entity.local")

`com.yourapp.config.MyConfigTest` <- config with annotation @Profile("test") and @EntityScan(basePackages = "com.yourapp.entity.test")

`com.yourapp.config.MyConfigCustom` <- config with annotation @Profile("custom") and @EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.yourapp.entity.local", "com.yourapp.entity.test"})

`com.yourapp.entity.local` <- package that contains only local entities

`com.yourapp.entity.test` <- package that contains only test entities

Remember, tables in DB may not disappear, it depend on hibernate configuration.